# Checar se hora atual está no raio definido no banco de dados

Tags: java, android

Eu queria saber como fazer para ver se a hora atual do sistema está dentre um raio previamente definido

Atualmente tenho esse código, mas sempre retorna "Fechado no momento"

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   final Date horaCheck = calendar.getTime();

   try{
    String horaAbre = getmHoraAbre();
    Date hourAbre = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(horaAbre);
    String horaFecha = getmHoraFecha();
    Date hourFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(horaFecha);

    if (horaCheck.after(hourAbre) && horaCheck.before(hourFecha)) {
        disponivelInfo.setText("Aberto no momento");

    } else {
        disponivelInfo.setText("Fechado no momento");
    }

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O sqlite suporta o time nas consultas, porém ele busca dados em horas, minutos e segundos (HH:mm:ss) então se você passar neste formato (HH:mm) vai dar erro.
Primeiro converte sua data para o formato válido e depois faça a consulta:

```
String dataFinalIn;
    String dataFinalOut;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        //HORA FECHAMENTO
        String horaFecha = getmHoraFecha();
        Date hourFecha = formato.parse(horaFecha);
        dataFinalIn = formato.format(hourFecha);
        //HORA ABERTURA
        String horaAbre = getmHoraAbre();
        Date hourAbre = formato.parse(horaFecha);
        dataFinalIn = formato.format(hourAbre );

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Agora fça essa consulta dentro de um cursor:

```
"select * from tabela where time(tabela.data_cadastro) between '"+dataFinalIn+"' and '"+dataFinalOut+"'"
```

Lembrando que tem que ser String no formato HH:mm:ss, então faça a conversão direitinho. Bjs

Comment: Eu estou usando o Firebase, desculpe, esqueci de falar

Comment: Eu tive experiências com data e hora formatada no firebase e não foram muito boas, principalmente para as consultas. Recomendo trabalhar com a hora em milisegundos.

Comment: Sua opinião é de grande ajuda, valeu pela dica